# Image Data Binding not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, data-binding

Here i want to display images in dynamic list and image is taking source from data binding LineFour, Here is the Code.

```
 <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding LineFour}" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
```

I have this in Load Data

```
public void LoadData()
        {
            // Sample data; replace with real data
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 1", LineTwo = "hill 1", LineThree = "monu 1", LineFour="file3"});
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 2", LineTwo = "hill 2", LineThree = "monu 2", LineFour="file2" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 3", LineTwo = "hill 3", LineThree = "monu 3", LineFour="file3" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 4", LineTwo = "hill 4", LineThree = "monu 4", LineFour = "file2" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 5", LineTwo = "hill 5", LineThree = "monu 5", LineFour = "file3" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 6", LineTwo = "hill 6", LineThree = "monu 6", LineFour = "file2" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 7", LineTwo = "hill 7", LineThree = "monu 7", LineFour = "file3" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 8", LineTwo = "hill 8", LineThree = "monu 8", LineFour = "file2" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 9", LineTwo = "hill 9", LineThree = "monu 9", LineFour = "file3" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "beach 10", LineTwo = "hill 10", LineThree = "monu 10", LineFour = "file2" });

            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }
```

Now the problem is images are not displaying? what to do ?

Comment: from where do you get this images? Are those in the project or taken online or other source?

Answer (score 1):

Go through this link

Basically providing direct url to source do not work u need to use a converter . after all Source proerty accepts an Image url but assigns a bitmap  / image source object to the image control

[data binding images](http://chris.59north.com/post/2010/10/18/Data-binding-images-with-MVVM.aspx)

so basic concept is using a converter :-)